# How to label to restrict build to agent nodes to use by using parameterized build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

For my Jenkins job, I have setup an environment parameter which tells my build script which configuration to use.  I also have slave nodes running on each of my environments to build and deploy my application.

I have tried used the "Restrict where this project can be run" with the value

```
buildnode-${ENV}
```

where ENV is the name of my parameter.  This doesn't seem to work as label does not perform substitution.

I have also tried the [NodeLabel Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin#NodeLabelParameterPlugin-Label), which allows me to define which nodes to run the job from.  However, this will create two separate selections:

[image]

Is there a way to tie this two together, so when I select QA environment, for example, the slave node for the QA server is choose to run the build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following work-around: have two builds - *A* and *B*. *A* will set up the environment, save it into a file, and pass the file as a parameter to build *B*, along with the name of the node on which to run (the parameters will be passed via [Parameterized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)). *B* will read the environment (via [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)) and run the build on the node passed as the other parameter (you do need to use NodeLabel plugin).

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try.  Or maybe I should just learn how to develop a Jenkins plugin and do it myself....

Comment: http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2014/03/01/jenkins-on-demand-slave-selection-through-labels/ this guy have same problem with elegant solution